# How to make charts in rails using csv/json files stored in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, charts

I have some csv/json data sets  and a  **State** *(province of country)* **model** in my appication.
Now I wanna make another model **Data** and gonna  relate it as follow :

> **state**  -->  *has_many:data*

**Data Model** attributes must be the files in csv/json format
My state model has one attribute :

> *name:string*

now when the current user's  location matches the state model's *name string* 
I want to show the  graphs in the profile page of user  the graphs must be from DATA model's(contains csv / json files).

**Question 1:** *How do I store csv/json files in model ?*

**Question 2:**  *How do I make charts using csv and json files contained in rails model ?*

Comment: Why on earth would you store CSV in a database? Its the worst serialization format ever.

Comment: I have my data sets in csv and json formats for each state  and I want to create charts out of them.. !

Comment: You should start by importing them into a database and normalizing the data.

Comment: they are big files !!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save very large JSON and CSV files clearly your best option is to store your data in the file system and only store the path reference in the database cells. For this I recommend using the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.

Now if for some reason you need to store the files directly in a cell of the database, I recommend parse your CSV file to a valid JSON, and after that, use [Postgress + hstore](http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails) or [Mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid) to store a document.